# Thread interruptions are not caught by InterruptedException

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a controller and a thread that does some work, the controller has an interrupt function that shuts off the threads in emergency situation.

the skeleton of my code looks something like this:

```
public class SomeController{

private Thread th;
public SomeController(){
    th = null;
}
public void Input(int state){
    switch(state){
    case 0: //emergency shut off
        if(th != null){
            th.sleep(1000); //make thread sleep first, still no effect
            th.interrupt();
         }
        break;
    case 1: //thread creation
        th = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    DoSomeWork();
                    }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    EmergencyProcedures();
                }
            }
            });
        th.start();
        break;
    }
}
```

However, when interrupt is called, the InterruptedException is never caught. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but do you mind to elaborate? I set a breakpoint at the interruption point and the thread property seemed to match the one I wanted to interrupt?

Comment: I have added another point: does `DoSomeWork` support interruption (for example by checking the interrupt status regularly)?

Comment: Does `DoSomeWork()` throw InterruptedException anywhere based on whether the thread is interrupted()? Can you show use the throws clause of `DoSomeWork()` ?

Comment: You can use jvisualvm (located in your JDK install/bin/) to know what exactly happens.

Comment: 1) `th.sleep` doesn't make another thread sleep. The `sleep` function makes the *current* thread sleep. 2) You won't catch `InterruptedException` unless `DoSomeWork` *throws* such an exception if it's interrupted. Does it?

Comment: Oh DoSomeWork does throw `InterruptedException` in the declaration, however, I don't think it has an active mechanism that checks `interrupted()`. Maybe that's the problem. I thought `interrupt()` would just magically stall the thread.

Comment: @Yonk: That would be a disaster. What if it stalled the thread while it held a critical lock? What if it stalled the thread while the thread left some shared data in an inconsistent state? If it did that, it would be totally unusable. A thread can only be interrupted at precise points where it knows how to be interrupted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only possibilities that come to mind:

- you are not interrupting the thread (are you sure `th.interrupt()` is called?)
- you interrupt another thread
- the thread gets interrupted but there is a problem in EmergencyProcedures that makes you think it was not interrupted
- you never start the thread and therefore you can't interrupt it.
- `DoSomeWork()` ignores the interruption

Comment: thanks, I've been tracing it for almost an hour now. it definitely hit `th.interrupt()` and the thread is definitely doing work (reflected on the GUI). From what it looks like, I never changed `th` to point to any other threads, so it should be pointing to the one I wanted to terminate. Now, I wasn't aware `DoSomeWork` could ignore interrupt, what elements could cause it to ignore?

Comment: For example, if you are running a calculation in a loop, you need to add something like `if(Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()) throw new InterruptedException();` in the loop body - otherwise the loop will continue running, ignoring the interruption.

Comment: In other words, if `DoSomeWork` does not specifically handle interruptions and does not regularly call any interruptible methods (like `Thread.sleep()`), it means it ignores them.

Comment: so if I understand it correctly, `interrupt()` is simply a flag. it still needs the thread itself to handle it?

Comment: @Yonk Yes that's basically it.

Comment: It's the worst-named boolean flag in history, (unless, someone knows better?).

Comment: @assylias maybe a bit off topic. Is there situations where Thread handles `interrupt()` automatically? or does it always expect the programmer to manually throw it?

Comment: @Yonk no - as explained by Marko Topolnik, interruption is a collaborative process in Java. The interrupting and interrupted sides have to work together.

Answer (score 4):

At least this is a problem with your code:

```
th.sleep(1000); //make thread sleep first, still no effect
```

You can't make another thread sleep: you'll make the current thread sleep only. You are just calling the `static sleep` method through an instance of `Thread`.

Calling `th.interrupt()` will not automatically cause the `InterruptedException` to be thrown within the other thread. That will happen only if the thread's code enters an interruptible method (one that declares `InterruptedException`).

Your main misconception (probably) is with the nature of the `interrupt` mechanism. Unlike the deprecated `stop` mechanism, `interrupt` is cooperative and therefore optional: the thread only receives an interrupt signal and is responsible to check its state explicitly. It can respond to the signal in any way it sees fit.

Comment: That is probably my problem right there. Let me try to implement a mechanism that constantly checks `isInterrupted()`. meanwhile, is there a forced mechanism that stops a thread?

Comment: As I mention, `stop` is such a mechanism, but it will probably cause more problems than it solves. Killing a thread in the middle of what it's doing can't be a sound approach.

Comment: gotcha. Since `DoSomeWork()` is doing sequencial work, is there some common ways to check for `isInterrupted` flag instead of inserting `if(isInterrupted()) throw new InterruptedExcept();` after each line of code?

Comment: No, that would be it. However, be careful not to overdo it: only check after **a lengthy task**.

Comment: Note that if this mechanism doesn't do what you want, you are welcome to code your own mechanism to interrupt a thread. This is here if it's convenient for you, but you are welcome to do thread interruption some other way.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz One advantage of using the common mechanism is better integration. You may one day use your code in a setting where some outside code wants to interrupt you. Also, you'll typically end up calling into methods from other APIs that are interruptible by this mechanism. This is sort-of the point of having a common interruption mechanism: it is a cross-cutting concern. The weaknesses of the mechanism itself are another story...

Comment: I agree that the fact that this mechanism is standard is a big factor weighing in favor of using it. But if you really don't like it, you are welcome to code any thread interruption mechanism you like. The threads have to cooperate anyway.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The main point is that then you'll have **two** mechanisms: the one everyone else is already using plus your custom mechanism. The existing mechanism is simply inescapable: it's there in your face whenever you call an interruptible method from the JDK, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are correctly calling `th.interrupt();`, it must be the case that the interrupt is not being 'noticed' in any reasonable amount of time. Interrupts do not magically get thrown the moment you call `interrupt()` on a thread. The thread, generally speaking, must detect when it has been interrupted, and throw its own `InterruptedException`.

Now, this is not usually a problem, as `Thread.sleep()` and a few other commonly used methods are designed to throw an `InterruptedException` immediately.

You need to check `Thread.interrupted()` once in a while manually, this will tell you whether or not the thread has been interrupted, which gives you a construct something like;

```
if (Thread.interrupted()) {
    throw new InterruptedException();
}
```

Which you would put inside `DoSomeWork();`.

`DoSomeWork();` *does* throw `InterruptedException` right?

Comment: note that `Thread.interrupted` clears the interrupted status, which is not necessarily desirable.

Comment: Yep thats a good point, thankyou. The interruption *must* be handled when `interrupted()` returns true.

Answer (score 1):

Like @assylias  said, or your thread is not supporting an interruption, see Supporting Interruption section from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html. 
Basically you need to use a method that supports the interruption, like sleep or Thread.interrupted().

Answer (score 0):

Are you interrupting after the sleep has finished. As per the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long), or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(), join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an InterruptedException.

Answer (score 0):

See first thing you have created `Thread` th but you did not start it. Second thing you can not catch `InterruptedException` exception inside run method.  Please try this in switch status 1.

```
           th = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    System.out.println("Run");
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    EmergencyProcedures();
                }
            }
            });
```

Comment: oops overlooked that, it's started in my real code though. fixed, thanks!

Comment: do you mind elaborating the part where you can't catch InterruptedException inside run method?

Comment: `InterruptedException` is a checked exception. If nothing as such in run method which arise this then you can not put it. As example sleep throws this exception.